# Get list element with minimum distance in relation to a point

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `WorldObject`. In this class I save a Position.

Now I have a List of `WorldObjects`. I want to find one element, that has the minimum distance to a given point.

```
abstract class WorldObject
{
    private Vector2D _position;

    public Vector2D Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }

    //...
}
```

```
private List<WorldObject> worldObjects;

internal WorldObject GetNearestObject(Vector2D pos)
{
    return worldObjects.Min();
}
```

Normally I can search the minimum by implementing `IComparable` in `WorldObject`. But now I need this one point as relation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
return worldObjects
    .Aggregate((result, current) => (current.Position.GetDistance(pos)
                                     < result.Position.GetDistance(pos))
                                    ? current : result);
```

`.GetDistance` is assumed function for calculating distances between `Vector2D` objects.

Another possibility is to use morelinq's [`.MinBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview):

```
return worldObjects.MinBy(wo => wo.Position.GetDistance(pos));
```

Yet another possibility, however it sorts the objects unnecessarily:

```
return worldObjects.OrderBy(wo => wo.Position.GetDistance(pos)).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have someway to get a distance between 2 positions:

```
internal WorldObject GetNearestObject(Vector2D pos)
{
    var minDistance = worldObjects.Min(wo => wo.Position.GetDistance(pos));
    return worldObjects.First(wo => wo.Position.GetDistance(pos) == minDistance);
}
```

Comment: The most probable result of `.GetDistance` is `double` or `float`. You shouldn't compare them with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

```
internal WorldObject GetNearestObject(Vector2D pos)
{
    return worldObjects.OrderBy(wo => wo.Position.GetDistance(pos)).First();
}
```

Comment: Linq isn't fast anyway it's mostly for convenience...
In order to do it quickly he should use QuadTree and iterate only on the relevant objects.